# A conditional normal rv sequence, does the mean converges in probability

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

$X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$, are $n$ mutually independent r.v.s. $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are another set of mutually independent r.v.s. $X_k\mid Y_k=y_k\sim N(y_k,y_k^2)$ and $Y_k\sim\text{uniform}(-k,k)$ for $k=1,\dots,n$. Define $\bar{X}_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}$ the sample mean of $X_i$'s.

I've calculated E$[\bar{X}_n]=0$ and Var$(\bar{X}_n)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{9n^2}=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{9n}$.

How can we prove that $\bar{X}_n$ doesn't converge to E$[\bar{X}_n]$ in probability?

Thanks!

Comment: Notice that the variance of $\bar X_n$ gets bigger as $n$ grows, not smaller. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes, the convergence of variance is highly (cor-)related to the convergence of a r.v. sequence. But can we prove that the convergence of the variance is a necessary condition for the sequence being convergent? Intuitively it is not convergent, can we prove it more rigorously?

Comment: You certainly had to use information about the distribution of $X_k$ in order to do your computations. What did you find?

Comment: $f_{X_k}(x)=\int_yf_{x_k,y_k}(x,y)dy=\int_{-k}^k\frac{exp[-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2y^2}]}{\sqrt{2\pi}y}dy$. I don't know how to calculate the integral.